# Volatility formulas in Sinclair's "Volatility Trading" book differs from TTR

Tags: volatility

In "Volatility Trading" Euan Sinclair defines Yang-Zhang volatility estimator as

$$ \sigma = \sqrt{\sigma^2_o + k\sigma^2_c + (1-k)\sigma^2_{rs}} $$

where
$$ 
\sigma^2_o \propto Variance\left(ln\left(\frac{o_i}{o_{i-1}}\right)\right) 
$$
$$ \sigma^2_c \propto Variance\left(ln\left(\frac{c_i}{c_{i-1}}\right)\right) $$
$$
\sigma^2_{rs} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N 
\left(
  \left(ln \frac{h_i}{c_i}\right) 
  \left(ln \frac{h_i}{o_i}\right) + 
  \left(ln \frac{l_i}{c_i}\right)
  \left(ln \frac{l_i}{o_i}\right) 
\right)
$$

/* I'm using $\propto$ symbol as "proportional to" to avoid unbiasing the $Variance$ via multiplying $Variance$ by $\frac{N}{N-1}$. See the actual formulas on the screenshot below in the References. */

However, TTR package [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbbcn.png) uses different formulas for $\sigma_o^2$, $\sigma_c^2$:

$$ 
\sigma^2_o \propto Variance\left(ln\left(\frac{o_i}{c_{i-1}}\right)\right) 
$$
$$ \sigma^2_c \propto Variance\left(ln\left(\frac{c_i}{o_{i}}\right)\right) $$

I plotted Garman-Klass, Parkinson, Yang-Zhang (TTR and Sinclair's) estimators on a chart:

[image: chart with various volatility estimators]

It shows how Sinclair's Yang-Zhang definition systematically deviates (and overestimates?) the volatility compared to the rest of the estimators.

**Question**

Does Sinclair's formula have a typo?

**References**

- TTR volatility [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TTR/versions/0.23-4/topics/volatility)

[image: TTR Yang-Zhang volatility estimator]

- Yang-Zhang volatility estimator from Sinclair's book: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbijZ.jpg)
  [image: yang-zhang volatility from Sinclair's book]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### When in doubt, consult the [original paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/209650#metadata_info_tab_contents):

In the beginning of the paper, the authors describe the following definitions for the normalized open and close (*p. 479*):

\begin{align*}
o&=\ln(O_1) - \ln(C_0) = \ln\left(\frac{O_1}{C_0}\right), \quad \text{normalized open;}\\
c&=\ln(C_1) - \ln(O_1)= \ln\left(\frac{C_1}{O_1}\right), \quad \text{normalized close.}
\end{align*}

Furthermore in *Section II* they define their volatility estimator as (*pp. 482 - 488*):

\begin{align*}
V &= V_O + k \cdot V_C + (1-k) \cdot V_{RS}\\
V_O&= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (o_i - \bar{o})^2\\
V_C&= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (c_i - \bar{c})^2\\
\bar{o}&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n o_i\\
\bar{c}&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n c_i,\\
\end{align*}
where $V_{RS}$ is derived later in the paper. Writing out one of the variance measures — using the notation from the original paper — gives you a clear indication that **the `TTR` package** has defined the Yang-Zhang estimator as originally intended:
\begin{align*}
V_O&= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (o_i - \bar{o})^2\\
&=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(o_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n o_i\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\ln\left(\frac{O_i}{C_{i-1}}\right) - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\left(\frac{O_i}{C_{i-1}}\right)\right)^2\\
&=V_O^{\text{TTR}}.
\end{align*}
You can do the same derivation for $V_C$. **Yes, I believe Sinclair has a few mistakes in his book**.

Comment: The quality of questions and answers here is unmatched. Thank you Pleb!